# Sketch: scaling relative to reference point

Tags: sketch-app, resize, anchor-point

How can I scale and/or transform objects relative to a reference point similar to the way Illustrator works? Is there a similar feature in Sketch?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, you have the option to scale from a reference point. By default, your copy of Sketch should have the Scale option in the toolbox. Once you open up the window, you should see the same grid as in Illustrator.

[image]

Comment: I suppose there is no way of achieving this behaviour when you are just using the handles on the object itself to resize?